# Python: While loops won't stop

Tags: python, loops

currently working on a project for python where we must develop a POS system. For our menu, it needs to be a loop. We are not the best "developers" what so ever but would love some insight. We need the menu to loop back to the main options after a user completes a function.

```
def main():
    mainMenu = 'Main Menu:  \n   1. Checkout  \n   2. Returns  \n   3. Additonal Items  \n   4. Item Reference'
    Option1 = "Inititiate Transaction:  \n    scan item  \n    remove item  \n    accept payment  \n    display receipt  \n    back"
    Option2 = "Returns: \n   initiating returns \n   refund money \n   remove item from transaction \n   back"
    Option3 = "Additonal Items: \n   initiating transaction \n   enter new item information \n   display item confirmation \n   back"
    Option4 = "Item Reference: \n   lookup \n   scan item for info \n   display item info \n   back"



    print(mainMenu)
    userInput=(input("Please select a number: "))
    while userInput!="0":
        if userInput=="1":
            print(Option1)
            break
        elif userInput=="2":
            print(Option2)
            break
        elif userInput=="3":
            print(Option3)
            break
        elif userInput=="4":
            print(Option4)
            break
        elif userInput=="0":
            print(mainMenu)
            break


main()
```

Comment: Don't break out of the loop if you want to keep displaying options.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you want to do is loop back to the main menu, so you should be calling the function to print the main menu and take user input inside the while loop.

```
def main():
    mainMenu = 'Main Menu:  \n   1. Checkout  \n   2. Returns  \n   3. Additonal Items  \n   4. Item Reference'
    Option1 = "Inititiate Transaction:  \n    scan item  \n    remove item  \n    accept payment  \n    display receipt  \n    back"
    Option2 = "Returns: \n   initiating returns \n   refund money \n   remove item from transaction \n   back"
    Option3 = "Additonal Items: \n   initiating transaction \n   enter new item information \n   display item confirmation \n   back"
    Option4 = "Item Reference: \n   lookup \n   scan item for info \n   display item info \n   back"



userInput = 10
while userInput!="0":
    print(mainMenu)
    userInput=(input("Please select a number:"))
    if userInput=="1":
        print(Option1)
        #perform the task here
    elif userInput=="2":
        print(Option2)
        #perform the task here
    elif userInput=="3":
        print(Option3)
        #perform the task here
    elif userInput=="4":
        print(Option4)
        #perform the task here
main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this code solve your task?

```py
def main():
    mainMenu = 'Main Menu:  \n   1. Checkout  \n   2. Returns  \n   3. Additonal Items  \n   4. Item Reference'
    Option1 = "Inititiate Transaction:  \n    scan item  \n    remove item  \n    accept payment  \n    display receipt  \n    back"
    Option2 = "Returns: \n   initiating returns \n   refund money \n   remove item from transaction \n   back"
    Option3 = "Additonal Items: \n   initiating transaction \n   enter new item information \n   display item confirmation \n   back"
    Option4 = "Item Reference: \n   lookup \n   scan item for info \n   display item info \n   back"

    print(mainMenu)
    userInput=(input("Please select a number: "))
    while userInput != "0":
        if userInput=="1":
            print(Option1)
            print(mainMenu)
            userInput=(input("Please select a number: "))
        elif userInput=="2":
            print(Option2)
            print(mainMenu)
            userInput=(input("Please select a number: "))
        elif userInput=="3":
            print(Option3)
            print(mainMenu)
            userInput=(input("Please select a number: "))
        elif userInput=="4":
            print(Option4)
            print(mainMenu)
            userInput=(input("Please select a number: "))
    print("Exiting")

main()
```